# How to install pktstat on centos7?

Tags: linux, networking, installation, centos

I am trying to install a package called netstat but I can't, I tried downloading and installing rpm file, but it was no use I tried making repos but I don't know if I am doing it the right way. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am using centos 7

Comment: So which package are you trying to instal? pktstat or netstat?

Comment: I actually want pkstat but I cant get it installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  install pkstat in centos 7 using Yum comamnd,

Please follow the below steps

(i) yum search pkstat.

(ii) Now get the package shown in the output of the first command and try to install

yum install pkstat.xx

Now you would be able to use the command once it is done.

Comment: Got `Warning: No matches found for: pkstat`

Comment: I'm guessing this should say `pktstat` everywhere, not `pkstat`

Comment: Even with `pktstat`, it's not working. `No matches` in CentOS 6.4. `No matches` in CentOS 7.2